# Getting access to item properties of an overview from Layout Designer using QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layouts

I try to establish an automated process for atlas printing. However, I am not able to get access to the drawing properties of the overview map of my layout. I want to have set the frame style of the overview within my python code.
I tried to read the API and thought that probably the class `QgsLayoutItemMapOverview.draw` is the right direction. The 'draw' methods accepts parameters defined in the `QPainter` (https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtGui/QPainter.html)
There I could find a lot of options concerning rendering but not exactly the options I want to address. Maybe it is the wrong direction.

I thought there must be an easy solution like

```
overviewMap.overview().setMapFrame()
```

Where can I set those properties?

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far? We can only reopen your question if edit it and asked a more focused question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an approach to access first overview stroke color. With this you should mostly have enough informations to then manipulate part you want

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layoutName = 'layout_atlas'
layout = manager.layoutByName(layoutName)

# Considering you selected the QgsLayoutItemMap in the GUI
layoutMapItem = layout.selectedLayoutItems()[0]
# Considering you already set an overview on QgsLayoutItemMap with the GUI
layoutMapItem.overviews()[0].setEnabled(True)
print(layoutMapItem.overviews()[0].frameSymbol().symbolLayer(0).strokeColor().name())
```

With the sample above, you need to look for methods of `layoutMapItem.overviews()[0].frameSymbol().symbolLayer(0)` to manipulate frame style. It's the methods of [`QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer.html)

Comment: Yes Thank you that helped. I jsut wanted to add 
```overviewMap.overview().setLinkedMap(mainMap)```
to give set the map whcih the overview is referenced to.